# Laravel 8 uploading two images seperately. added same image names in database

Tags: laravel-8, image-upload

This is the controller code:

```
 $player1QID = time().'.'.$request->player1_Id->extension(); 
    $images1= $request->player1_Id->move(public_path('images'), $player1QID);
   
    $player2QID = time().'.'.$request->player2_Id->extension();  
     
    $images2= $request->player2_Id->move(public_path('images'), $player2QID);
```

///this is adding to database:

```
       $registeredusers = Registrations::create([
        'tournament_id' => $request->input('tournament_id'),
         'player1_name' => $request->input('player1_name'),
         'player1_email' => $request->input('player1_email'),
         'player1_Id' => $player1QID,
         'player1_gender' => $request->player1_gender,
         'player1_phone' => $request->input('player1_phone'),
         'player2_name' => $request->input('player2_name'),
          'player2_email' => $request->input('player2_email'),
          'player2_Id' => $player2QID,
         'player2_gender' => $request->player2_gender,
         'player2_phone' => $request->input('player2_phone'),
          'category' => $request->category,
          'status' => $request->input('status'),
        
       
        
    ]);
```

This is in view blade:

Upload image1

*Upload image2*

Really appreciate if someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should first look at your inspection in Chrome, Firefox or whatever you are using, and check what your request contains, I mean if you are sending the images in separate names like:
...
player1_Id:
player2_Id:
...
i think, of course is sending like that because you are receiving it on your controller. Then try save it with datetime at end of name like:

```
public function obtainImage(Request $request){

$image1=request('player1_Id');

$this->manageImage($image1);

$image2=request('player2_Id');

$this->manageImage($image2);
}
```

public function manageImage($image){
$fileImageNameExtencion=$image->getClientOriginalName();

```
  $fileName=pathInfo($fileImageNameExtencion, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

  $fileExtencion=$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

  $newFileName=$fileName."_".time().".".$fileExtencion;

  $saveAs=$image->storeAs('public/images',$newFileName);
  return $newFileName;
```

}

where $ newFileName is what you need to save to your database

otherwise you can do a dd ($ player1QID. '-'. $ player2QID) before saving to database and comparing names

Comment: i tried doing this:dd ($ player1QID. '-'. $ player2QID) ,,but I got same name for both images...specifically second image name

Comment: i checked by dd()..after adding your function its getting different image names for database storage..but files are not saved in images folder

Comment: Thank you Mr.Subhashis Pandey....I solved the issue of not saving by adding this code:$request->player1_Id->move(public_path('images'), $QID1);
      
   $request->player2_Id->move(public_path('images'), $QID2);